# Can std::string reallocation invalidate pointer to heap?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, heap-memory, invalidation

My question is regarding the following scenario:

```
std::string *ps = new std::string();
*ps = aVeryLargeString;
```

What usually happens from my experience is that aVeryLargeString exceeds the capacity of *ps, so *ps allocates extra memory, *keeping the starting position the same.* So ps will still point to the new string as the location in memory is the same.

However, what happens if there is not enough contiguous space at that memory location? Does the reallocation move the string to a completely different place, thus invalidating the pointer?

Comment: `std::string` has an internal pointer. If it needs to reallocate, the internal pointer will change; your pointer to the `std::string` will not. It's almost like you have a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: In fact, it's *exactly* like you have a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: In fact, it's having a pointer to a pointer. With a little additional structural information.

Comment: In fact, it's *exactly* having a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: I think I just might have broken the funnyness in this. I apologize.

Comment: Is it a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: Why is everyone saying "in fact", followed by statements which are false?

Comment: Can you access this internal pointer? For my pointer, if the reallocation does happen, does it basically mean I can't access the string anymore?

Comment: Of course you can still access the string. Why are you `new`ing a string anyway? That's an unusual use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What usually happens from my experience is that aVeryLargeString
>   exceeds the capacity of *ps, so *ps allocates extra memory, keeping
>   the starting position the same.

No, this is not generally true. When you exceed the capacity, the string uses its allocator to allocate a completely different block (with size some factor of the previous capacity), and copies the characters over. Unless you keep a pointer or reference to the actual characters of the string (e.g. via `&(*ps)[0]`, or `ps->c_str()`), as opposed to a pointer to the string object itself (which is what `ps` is), you don't have to worry about this.

> So ps will still point to the new string as the location in memory is
>   the same.

`ps` is not, and cannot be, affected in any way by an operation on the string it points to (`*ps`) (*obviously excluding operations which exhibit undefined behavior, which can have any effect whatsoever*).

Comment: Right, I think I got it, correct me if I'm wrong: ps points to a string, which itself has a char array member to store the raw data. When I assign to ps it creates a new char array, and updates the strings char array member with the new one, leaving ps intact?

Comment: @JamesLens: When you assign to `ps`? Or when you assign to `*ps`? When you assign to `ps`, very little happens. Just a pointer assignment, and a memory leak if you don't have a copy of it. When you assign to `*ps`, it is as you say.

Comment: @JamesLens: *"it is as you say"* -- Let me retract that. When you assign to `*ps`, it calls the assignment operator of `std::string`, which may create a new char array, or it may just reuse the one it already has if there is enough space to copy over the characters of the other string.